# Plot multiple box-plots using columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, boxplot

I have a dataframe with a column of categorical data (two possible values) and multiple variable columns. I need to plot multiple box-plots, one for each variable column. Each plot compares the value of the variable between the two categorical groups given in column 1. So far I have it working by writing an individual plot call for each column.

```
#CREATE DATASET
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rlnorm(30*10,meanlog=0,sdlog=1), nrow=30))
colnames(mydata) <- c("categ", "var1","var2", "var3","var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9")
mydata$var2 <- mydata$var2*5
mydata$categ <- sample(1:2)
mydata

#LAYOUT
par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar=c(4,4,0.5,0.5), mgp = c(1.5, 0.3, 0), tck = -0.01)

#BOXPLOTS
boxplot(var1 ~ categ, data = mydata, outpch = NA, ylim = c(0, 8), Main = "Title", ylab="VarLevel", tck = 1.0, names=c("categ1","categ2"))
stripchart(var1 ~ categ, data = mydata, vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", ylim = c(0, 8), pch = 21, cex = 1, col=c(rgb(255, 0, 0, 100, max = 255), rgb(0, 0, 255, 100, max = 255)), bg = rgb(255, 255, 255, 10, max = 255), add = TRUE)
test <- wilcox.test(var1 ~ categ, data = mydata)
pvalue <- test$p.value
pvalueformatted <- format(pvalue, digits=3, nsmall=2)
mtext(paste(colnames(mydata)[2], " p = ", pvalueformatted), side=1, line=-13, at=0.9, cex = 0.6)

boxplot(var2 ~ categ, data = mydata, outpch = NA, ylim = c(0, 40), Main = "Title2", ylab="VarLevel", tck = 1.0, names=c("categ1","categ2"))
stripchart(var2 ~ categ, data = mydata, vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", ylim = c(0, 40), pch = 25, cex = 1, col=c(rgb(255, 0, 0, 100, max = 255), rgb(0, 0, 255, 100, max = 255)), bg = rgb(255, 255, 255, 10, max = 255), add = TRUE)
test <- wilcox.test(var2 ~ categ, data = mydata)
pvalue <- test$p.value
pvalueformatted <- format(pvalue, digits=3, nsmall=2)
mtext(paste(colnames(mydata)[3], " p = ", pvalueformatted), side=1, line=-13, at=0.9, cex = 0.6)
```

Two questions:
1) I would like to use a function or for loop to script the plot call for each data column. Not sure how to do this. I saw a few related posts but couldn't quite get there. Trying to use base functions for now, though could consider ggplot or others if necessary.
2) As part of the loop/function, is there a way to adjust the y-axis scale of each plot to accommodate the range of the variable? So for a given column, if the maximum value is 2, the y axis scale would go up to 4. If the max was 100, the y axis would go up to 110.

Thoughts appreciated

Comment: A nice, reproducible question - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would `sapply` over a vector of column numbers and subset `mydata` to the column of interest within the function. By iterating over column numbers rather than columns themselves, you have easy access to the correct `colname` to be added to the plot later.

You also need to add a small outer margin (`oma`) to side 3 (top) so that the p value can be printed there for the first 3 plots.

To address your second question - that of reducing the y limits to fit the range of the data - this will be automatic if you specify `outline=FALSE` to suppress plotting of outliers. (In your code, you simply supplied `NA` as the plotting character to hide them, but the `boxplots` still considered them part of the data when determining the axis limits.) However, by setting `outline=FALSE`, the y limits that are calculated will not accommodate any outliers that would otherwise be plotted by the call to `stripchart` (which I've now modified to `points` since it's a bit simpler).

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar=c(3, 3, 0.5, 0.5), mgp = c(1.5, 0.3, 0), tck = -0.01,
    oma=c(0, 0, 1, 0))

sapply(seq_along(mydata)[-1], function(i) {
  y <- mydata[, i]
  boxplot(y ~ mydata$categ, outline=FALSE, ylab="VarLevel", tck = 1.0, 
          names=c("categ1","categ2"), las=1)
  points(y ~ jitter(mydata$categ, 0.5), 
     col=ifelse(mydata$categ==1, 'firebrick', 'slateblue'))
  test <- wilcox.test(y ~ mydata$categ)
  pvalue <- test$p.value
  pvalueformatted <- format(pvalue, digits=3, nsmall=2)
  mtext(paste(colnames(mydata)[i], " p = ", pvalueformatted), side=3, 
        line=0.5, at=0.9, cex = 0.6)  
})
```

Note I've also modified your `mtext` call to plot on side 3 rather than specifying side 1 with a large negative margin.

[image: boxplots]

Comment: Arg.  You got there like 2 seconds before me. :)

Comment: We have been having quite the epic battle the past few days ;)

Comment: Terrific solution and exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. Trying to make sure I understand: What is seq_along doing? Also, with this solution, if there is a very large number of columns, how could I limit to say 12 plots per page? Would I have to break up my dataframe into separate 12-column dataframes?

Comment: You can test `seq_along` to check what it does. `seq_along(mydata)` returns an integer sequence from 1 to `length(mydata)`. It's equivalent to `1:ncol(mydata)` or `1:length(mydata)` in most cases (although if `mydata` is a matrix rather than a data frame length will cause problems). I drop the first element of the sequence since we don't treat the categories as data to be plotted.

Comment: Our specification of `mfrow=c(3, 3)` will ensure that only 9 plots are plotted. After that, a fresh plot window will be generated. If you want 4 rows of 3 instead, do `mfrow=c(4, 3)`. If you're using RStudio, you can scroll back and forth through the various plot windows and export them as desired. Alternatively, insert `png('some_boxplots%d.png')` before the entire `sapply` block, and `dev.off()` after it, and the `%d` in the filename will turn on pagination, with 4x3 plots named 'some_boxplots1.png', 'some_boxplots2.png', etc.

Comment: Just had a great R lesson. Thank you very much!