# WEIRD: sapply not working on dplyr::tbl_df() local data.frame

Tags: r, apply, dplyr, lapply, sapply

I haven't seen anyone post this error resulting from using `dplyr` in conjunction with `sapply` before, so I thought I'd ask if anyone knows why this occurs. It's not a major issue per se as the work-around is really easy, but it may spare some of you the hassle of wondering what on earth is going on. The sample data's taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876248/plot-multiple-box-plots-using-columns-of-dataframe-in-r), and I've made a variation of the code given by [jbaums](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489704/jbaums) in the same post.

#### Sample data

```
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rlnorm(30*10,meanlog=0,sdlog=1), nrow=30))
colnames(mydata) <- c("categ", "var1","var2", "var3","var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9")
mydata$var2 <- mydata$var2*5
mydata$categ <- sample(1:2)
mydata
```

#### Looped function for making multiple boxplots

```
sapply(seq_along(mydata)[-1], function(i) {
    y <- mydata[, i]
    names <- colnames(mydata)[i]
    plot(factor(mydata$categ), log(y + 1), main=names, ylab="foo",outpch=NA, las=1)
})
```

that works perfectly.

#### Now this error occurs after using `tbl_df()`

```
require(dplyr)
mydata2 <- tbl_df(mydata)
sapply(seq_along(mydata2)[-1], function(i) {
    y <- mydata2[, i]
    names <- colnames(mydata2)[i]
    plot(factor(mydata2$categ), log(y + 1), main=names, ylab="foo",outpch=NA, las=1)
})
 Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

The workaround is really simple, as it's just:

```
mydata2 <- data.frame(mydata2)
## OR
lapply(...)
```

and then the code runs smoothely again.

Any idea why this might be happening? I gather it's more an issue of `sapply` vs. `lapply`, but I found it quite intriguing.

Cheers,

O.

Comment: has this been answered or is there more to be figured out ? If you have another explanation feel free to post your own answer  (should the proposed not be adequate) and accept so all can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference how `[` works for each:

```
> mydata[,2]
 [1] 5.0044042 0.8456266 1.6407979 0.3850787 6.0767393 1.8768533 1.0071454 0.3674155 0.6573932 0.3614813
[11] 1.8037157 1.1420720 0.5842170 0.4632418 1.1114478 1.1753951 0.1077499 0.9043782 3.0877567 0.9421167
[21] 1.2429474 1.8952458 0.4592660 0.3842183 1.1274421 2.2946488 2.0904511 0.4132986 0.3421766 0.7592236

> mydata2[,2]
Source: local data frame [30 x 1]

        var1
1  5.0044042
2  0.8456266
3  1.6407979
4  0.3850787
5  6.0767393
6  1.8768533
7  1.0071454
8  0.3674155
9  0.6573932
10 0.3614813
..       ...
```

Therefore what you want to reproduce the intended behaviour *(**simplifying** instead of **preserving**)*:

`mydata2[[2]]`

note the class changes:

```
> class(mydata)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(mydata2)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(mydata2[,2])
[1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"
```

## from: `?tbl_df`

```
Methods

tbl_df implements two important base methods:

print
Only prints the first 10 rows, and the columns that fit on screen

[
Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame
```

Comment: So it's essentially an issue of how "the column format" for the apply function? Interesting.

Comment: @OFish the difference is the `tbl_df` method for `[` which always returns a `data.frame`. I've edited answer to make this more clear.