# Plot multiple box-plots (several numeric variables vs. one categorical variable) in R

Tags: r

My question is exactly the same to this link
[Plot multiple box-plots using columns of dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876248/plot-multiple-box-plots-using-columns-of-dataframe-in-r/33935990#33935990)

The only difference is that I have lots of NA among the numeric variables, I tried to run the suggested code by jbaums (you can see the suggested programming code in this link) but I got NULL as a results. Do you have any idea regarding fixing this issue. Thanks.

For example:

```
categ<-c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
var1 <- c(10:15,NA,NA,NA,34)
var2 <- c(100:115,NA,23,NA,34)
var3 <- c(20:25,NA,NA,NA,34)
var4 <- c(1000:1015,23,NA,NA,500)
var5 <- c(1:5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data.frame(categ,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the exact code you're running and a sample of your data? Just a `head(data)` or even just `str(data)` should be enough.

Looking at the docs for boxplot (`?boxplot` in the R console) suggests that the default behaviour is to ignore NA values, but you can try to set `na.action = NULL` in your call to boxplot. If it's not working then the problem is in the rest of your code.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, I just added a simple example. I have a very large data set including lots of NA among the columns.

Comment: Ok, using the example above and running the jbaums' script as-is, it worked for me. However, the console output does say "null" but I think that is the expected behaviour? Are you running this in R studio or in a console? The plots opened in a separate window for me. see the screenshot added to my answer.

Comment: Hi, I cannot get the box plots for some of the variables because of this error: Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]. Do you have any idea regarding fixing this problem?

Comment: how many factors do you have in your categorical data? it sounds like your names parameter is the wrong length, maybe try it without `names=c("categ1","categ2")` for now. the number of names should equal the number of factors.